# Artificial Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I ran an artificial neural network in Jupiter notebook. The first time, I got 95.83% accuracy. But, the second time I got only 19.95% accuracy. I don't understand why this type of result I got? (There is nothing changed in the code)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To be able to help you, you have to edit the question in a way that we can actually answer without making tons of conjecture. Please check the following guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In your case, a good start would be to provide code, so that we can check for mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Bit it is really for coding questions. Check out [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for general questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

As accuracy depends on the weights that are choosen intially, As it also depends on optimizer function i prefer to use (ADAM). In the first your weights are good and you got good accuracy but in second time i think your model stuck into a saddle point (where your loss doesn't increase or decrease)